# std::vector<std::pair<int, float>> and void error

Tags: c++, vector

I'd like to sort m_correlationValues in descending order and get ids of the sorted list. I've got this error. I'll appreciate your help.
no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::vector<std::pair<int, float> >' and 'void')
return idx_correlation.second; });

```
  void MatrixCanvas::SortMatrix()
  {
    int naxes = (int) m_correlationData.size();
    std::vector<std::pair<int,float>> idx_correlations;
    std::vector<std::pair<int,float>> sorted;
    std::vector<int> idxs(naxes);

    for(int idx =0; idx<naxes;idx++){
        idx_correlations[idx] = std::make_pair(idx, m_correlationValues[chosen_row_id][idx]);}

        // Wrong
        sorted = std::sort(idx_correlations.begin(),
                            idx_correlations.end(),
                            [](std::pair<int,float> &idx_correlation){
                            return idx_correlation.second; });

    // this will contain the order:
    for(int i =0; i<naxes;i++)
        idxs[i] = sorted[i].first;

}
```

Comment: Your sort predicate must (1) have a different signature, as  it's called with two arguments to be compared and (2) return a `bool` that indicates whether the first argument is to be considered "less"  than the second.

Comment: `std::sort` does not return anything. It sorts in place. When it returns `idx_correlations` will be sorted. If you want to keep that unsorted then you should make a copy first, like `sorted = idx_correlations` and pass iterators to `sorted` to `sort`. If you do fix that then prepare yourself for a really long error about the sort predicate that @lubgr mentioned. :)

Comment: `sorted = std::sort(idx_correlations.begin(),...`  -- What was your intention with this code?  This is not how `std::sort` works.

Comment: sorting pairs will have the following criteria: sort all pairs with respect to its first (x,y) the x here, and if equals it sorts by its second (x,y) the y here.

Comment: @Cece -- It doesn't matter what types you're sorting -- they could be simple `int`, `doubles`, `pairs`, or Widgets -- it doesn't matter.  The `std::sort` predicate takes two arguments of that type.  You are given two values, and you're supposed to return `true` or `false`, depending on whether the first value should be placed before the second value.  Maybe if you used modern C++ syntax using `auto`, things would be more understandable:  `std::sort(idx_correlations.begin(), idx.correlations.end(), [](auto& val1, auto& val2)...`.  What `auto` is will depend on the types that the vector holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. sort does not return a copy of the sorted range.  It modifies the range provided.  If you want the original to be left alone, make a copy of it *first* and then sort it.
2. `std::sort`'s third argument is a comparator between *two* values, which has the meaning of "less than".  That is, "does a come before b?"  For keeping the line short, I replaced your `pair<...>` type with `auto` in the lambda, but it'll be deduced to "whatever type of thing" is being sorted.

Note, if you want decreasing, just change `<` to `>` in the lambda when it compares the two elements.

Possible fix:

```
    auto sorted = idx_correlations; // full copy
    std::sort(sorted.begin(),
              sorted.end(),
              [](auto const & left, auto const & right) {
                   return left.first < right.first; });
```

After that, `sorted` will be a sorted vector and idx_correlations will be left unchanged.  Of course, if you don't mind modifying your original collection, there's no need to make this copy (and you can take begin/end of idx_correlations.

Comment: Thank you! I understand the logic now.

Answer (score 2):

So the main issue I can see in your code, is that you're expecting the `std::sort` to return the sorted vector, and this is NOT how it works.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

The solution in your case is to get the sorted vector out of the original vector, ie. `sorted = idx_correlations` then sort the new vector.

```
sorted = idx_correlations;
std::sort( sorted.begin(), sorted.end(), your_comparator... );
```

This will do the trick while also maintaining the original vector.

Update: another issue is that your comparator will have TWO arguments not one (two elements to compare for the sort).

Comment: Thank you! I understand the logic now.

Comment: No problem, my pleasure

Answer (score 1):

The other answers covered proper use of `std::sort`, I wish to show C++20 [`std::rannges::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/sort) which have projection functionality what is close to thing you've tried to do:

```cpp
    std::vector<std::pair<int, float>> idx_correlations;
     .....
    auto sorted = idx_correlations;
    std::ranges::sort(sorted, std::greater{}, &std::pair<int, float>::second);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4rzzqW9Gx

Comment: Thanks! My aim is to sort based on float numbers in the pair as I will use sorted ids later. Does this way focus on float values for sorting?

Comment: This part `&std::pair<int, float>::second`  says that. And `std::greater{}` says descending order.